# I Want to verify that Sum of 3 Row values is equal to the first row in on my WebTable using Selenium C#. The Rows are Row3, Row6 & Row8

Tags: c#, selenium

```
IList<IWebElement> rows = _driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@id='data_3']/div/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[@class]")); 
for (int i = 1; i <= rows.Count; i++)
{
    IList<IWebElement> columns = _driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@id='data_3']/div/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[@class][" + i + "]/td[@class]"));

    for (int j = 1; j <= columns.Count; j++)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the issue?

Comment: Can someone direct me in the right direction? I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Post a HTML of the elements you are working on.

Comment: i'm just looking for the logic to compare Row3+Row5+Row8 values equal to Row1 in every column. I tried several combinations, but can't figure it out.

Comment: its a simple WebTable and I'm using C#

Comment: The issue here, is to check whether the values in rows 3, 5, 8 are summed to value kept in row 1?
Seeing the HTML of the said table would make it easier to understand the problem. Also you could post the screenshot with the proper rows marked.

Comment: <tr class="row-1">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Grand Total Employment</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td data-r="" class="cell1 " align="right">1055
                    </td> <td data-r="" class="cell2 " align="right"> 0</td>
                    <td data-r="" class="cell3 " align="right" 0 </td>
                    <td data-r="" class="cell4 " align="right"> 527 </td>
                    <td data-r="" class="cell5 " align="right"> 528 </td>
</tr>..

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you need to sum values from three rows and check if it is equal to the value from the first one. I will use the path you have provided.

```
public int GetRowValue(int rowNumber)
{
    var row = _driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@id='data_3']/div/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[@class]"))[rowNumber - 1] // decreased by 1, because if you would like to get first row, it would have 0th index in the array
    var columns = row.FindElements(By.XPath("./td"); // find all tds of the given row.
    int value = 0;
    foreach(var column in columns)
      {
          if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(column.Text)) continue;
          result += Int32.Parse(column.Text);
      }
      return value;
}
```

With that, you can easily check what you want.

```
var row1Value = GetRowValue(1);
var sum = GetRowValue(3);
sum += GetRowValue(6);
sum += GetRowValue(8)
Assert.Equals(row1Value, sum);
```

Comment: This won't work since i'm working on a cucumber scenario step. I am not creating a new method. I need to know how to apply that formula across the entire table.

Comment: What problem do you have? Also, you should have include "cucumber" tag in the question, when you asked it.

Comment: GetRowValue(n) won't work since i'm not passing int into my method. i'm basically just trying to use different rows to add/compare formulas. I need something like row1+row2 == row1 or row3+row5<=row4+row7. I have 5 columns and I want to apply those kind of formulas on all the columns. I want a code that loops on all the columns and applies formulas at selected rows.

Comment: I think that with the snippet I have provided to you, you should easily revamp it to your needs. Initial question said nothing about those new requirements.

Comment: Jonah,  I just used the simplest example to explain what I want to do. But I need to find specific rows values and use them in formulas across all columns.

Comment: How would you iterate on a dynamic webTable using C# to achieve the above formulas?